# Rails / Postgres: Error after changing pg gem version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, bundler, gemset

I encounter this error message when running my specs after messing with gemsets and the pg gem version:

```
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # PG::UndefinedColumn:
 #   ERROR:  column "waiting" does not exist
 #   LINE 1: ...me AS source, age(now(), xact_start) AS duration, waiting, q...
 #                                                                ^
 #   /Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@xx/gems/pghero-1.4.2/lib/pghero/methods/basic.rb:84:in `select_all'
```

I've tried using both versions of pg gem that I've used yesterday(`0.18.4` and `0.19.0`) by specifiying the exact version in the Gemfile, installing them (`bundle install`) and confirmed that the version is in deed used by checking `Gemfile.lock`. Both keep producing the error.

I am not really experienced, especially with Postgres. I don't know how gems and OS-packages play together etc. So I wanted to know if anyone knows what's going on and give me a tip?

Thanks

Comment: can you try migrating once -> `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Did the specs run fine before this ? I think your test environment miss some migrations.

Comment: I ran migrations in test and dev environments

Comment: postgres 9.5 has column waiting in pg_stat_activity and 9.6 has wait_event_type instead - this causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following  questions and advices for you

- uninstall all pg gem version in your gemset
- uninstall pg hero gem
- run `bundle install`
- in case the error still resides then try upgrading the pghero gem - current version is 1.6.2 (mentioning this as your error states pghero)

Did you switch to another ruby version (even minor is relevant)? If so drop the whole gemset (`rvm gemset delete`) and run a fresh `bundle install`. This will build all native extensions against the updated ruby version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Postgres version. [in 9.6 pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html)

> ... replace the waiting column with wait_event_type and
>   wait_event.

As **workaround** you can try change in script, causing exception:

```
, age(now(), xact_start) AS duration, waiting,
```

to:

```
, age(now(), xact_start) AS duration, case when wait_event_type is null then false else true waiting,
```